# One Common Drop down list for entire table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I have a table with dynamic content. One of the column is type of `select option` (drop down). These `options` are same for all the table rows. So, I want to prepare on list and show this list when ever this column is selected.

Current HTML is

```
<tbody>
   <tr data-ng-repeat="item in items">
   <td>{{item.name}}</td>
   <td>
     <select>
        <option data-ng-repeat="option in item.options" 
               value="{{option.value}}">{{option.name}}</option>
     </select>
  </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I'm thinking to write new code like below

```
<tbody>
   <tr data-ng-repeat="item in items">
   <td>{{item.name}}</td>
   <td>
     <span>value <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></span>
  </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<dropdown-list></dropdown-list>
```

I need to show the similar display like above html. I mean drop down list should be shown at exact position. How can I do this??

Comment: Generate select box code in jquery and append it to td(column) using jquery append

Comment: Dropdown list will be out side table and I'm trying to show it on the table clicked cell